# PHP no me inserta y no muestra error

Tags: php

> Al insertar no muestra ningun error,como imprimir el error y mostrar en pantalla al insertar?.Gracias.

```
public function addCliente($ci,$nombres,$apellidos,$telefono,$grupo)
{
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contactos VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?)');
    //parametro a statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$ci,$nombres,$apellidos,$telefono,$grupo);
    //ejecutar el query
    $stmt->execute();
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: que es `$ci`? y por que si estas asignandole un valor tu mismo, luego lo metes a la función `bind_param()` ?

Comment: No me gustan esas sentencias `INSERT`  sin especificar las columnas. ¿Seguro que estás abarcando todas las columnas? ¿Y si un día la tabla evoluciona y tienes miles de sentencias en los que se omiten las columnas? Estarías ante un escenario muy pero que muy penoso... Dicho esto, vamos a capturar el error, poniendo: `if (!$stmt->execute() ) {echo "Error!: ".$this->conexion->error;}` esa línea sustituirá al `execute` actual que tienes.

Comment: @element el valor de `$ci` iría en la segunda columna de la tabla. Realmente los valores de `bind_param` coinciden: 5 marcadores x 5 valores. La 1ª columna tomaría siempre el valor `0`. Pero es una consulta implícita que siempre resulta poco clara porque no se ven las columnas. Si por ejemplo se omite una columna que no admite nulos va a tener problemas en la inserción. Si la 1ª columna es llave primaria o unique también fallará. Si un día la tabla evoluciona, ese código puede ser problemático por el hecho de que no nombra las columnas de forma explícita. Mala práctica escribir un `INSERT`así.